# Doubly Linked List delete last

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a reference to the head and lastNode.
Hi I have a question. When I delete the last node in a doubly linked list do I have to set the previous reference of the node to null or can I just leave it.
I do something like this when deleting the lastNode.

```
lastNode = lastNode.prev; // lets lastNode reference the new last node
lastNode.next = null; // removes link to the old last node
```

When I do the toString method it prints as expected. Just wondering if its necessary to set the old last node prev to null or not. Or will the garbage collector just delete it since theres no reference to it even though the old node still has a reference to a node in the linked list

Comment: Make sure you are updating your head pointer, if applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only need to update the reference to null if there was any way to access the newly deleted lastNode object.  If there is no way to reach this node by traversing the list, then you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Although, It is good practice to do this sort of cleanup just in case.

Comment: I would venture to say you definitely should always set the new lastNode's next pointer to null, as it's pointer should properly be pointed to the correct thing in memory. It doesn't fundamentally make sense to leave the pointer to an object in memory that doesn't exist (even if it is null in either case!).

Comment: I think he means the deleted node, not the new lastNode.  In a doubly linked list he would DEFINITELY have to update previous and next references of nodes still in the list.  I was referring to the removed node.

Comment: Not adding a new node just updating the references to remove the last node from the list. The lastNode has a reference to the next to last node with the above code I provided. I'm asking weather or not that matters or the garbage collector will delete it anyway since that is no reference to that node any longer

Comment: The GC will collect the old-last-node regardless if it points to the new-last- node or not. All that it cares about is that the old-last-node is not reachable. It is still a good practice to do so, for example, if something retains a reference to the old-last-node, that something will fail cleanly (NPE) when trying to traverse  (backwards) if the cleanup has been performed. Otherwise you may end up with a difficult to diagnose bug